# is there a way to find HTML element by type?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

There are several functions to get DOM document elements e.g. `.getElementById()`, `.getElementByName()` etc. but I do not see any function which would allow to get element by type.

Is there some mechanism to do it?

Comment: by type? what kind of elements are you expecting to get with that?

Comment: There's no `getElementByName` function. It's `getElementsByName` (plural "elements")

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `getElementsByTagName()` function to get all elements by their tag name.

I.e. `getElementsByTagName("div")` will return all <div>'s.

Comment: To be clear, `getElementsByTagName("div")` will get _"all"_ divs when called on the `document` object: `document.getElementsByTagName("div")` — all of these "getElement(s)By___" methods can be called on any element, so `document.getElementById("foo").getElementsByTagName("div")` will get all of the divs that are under the `id="foo"` element, _not_ all divs in the doc.

Answer (score 1):

CSS selectors via `.querySelectorAll` are most powerful.

```js
let p = document.querySelectorAll("p");
console.log(p[0].innerHTML + " and " + p[1].innerHTML);
```

```html
<p>asdf</p>
<span>fdafsdf</span>
<p>kjkjkj</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all elements by the type with 'document.querySelectorAll()' method.
As an example, you can get all the 'input' elements with type 'text' as follows.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"]')
```

Comment: Thank you Ronnie - this is perfect!

Comment: It can be very useful to get e.g. password input box with `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="password"]')